# Should I put all the logic in Laravel policies?

Tags: laravel, policy

In General should I put all the logic in laravel policies or just the authorization logic ?

For example .....

I have a **Currency Policy** which allows the admin to change the **base currency** only in this case :

1. The admin has this permission .
2. No products added to
   the system .

As you notice , **the condition (1)** is specific and obviously an authorization logic .

But **Condition (2)** is a general condition .

Now my question .....

Should I put (2) or any general conditions in controllers Or I should put It in policies ?

Comment: This is a bit subjective. I would argue that authorisation is asking whether a user can do something, not whether that something is do-able i.e. a user can upload files but you might be out of disk space

Comment: Thank you for your comment , It really clarifies the idea